# why log_message is not displaying the message in log file

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
public function delete($id){
  $bn = $this->Beneficiaries_model->get_real_beneficiary($id);
  $this->Beneficiaries_model->delete_beneficiary($id,$bn->project_id);
  redirect('projects/view/' . $bn->project_id);
  log_message('error', 'Some variable did not contain a value.');
}
```

Am i using in correct way? how can we see the error messages in php project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the page will be redirected before logging the message.

Change the order of last two lines as follows:

```
log_message('error', 'Some variable did not contain a value.');
redirect('projects/view/' . $bn->project_id);
```

Comment: @user3214656 You're welcome, Since you're new to Stackoverflow, please consider to mark and accept the answer which you have found it helpful.

Comment: please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21232026/why-trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-error-raised

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the threshold is set to log errors

Also it might help checking apache error logs

Comment: also log_message before redirect like Hashem has suggested

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your log files are writeable.

See http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/errors.html

Comment: yes.i have already gave the writable permission.i have used log_message by seeing this one.