# why Trying to get property of non-object error raised

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, ubuntu-13.10

> Severity: Notice  --> Trying to get property of non-object is showing for the line          $this->data['tasks'] = $workpackages->tasks;

```
public function view($id) {

    //get list of projects
    $project = $this->Projects_model->get_project($id);

    $rate = $this->ion_auth->get_project_rate($project->id)->row();

    if ($project) {
        //get list of beneficiaries
        $benificiaries = $this->Beneficiaries_model->get_beneficiaries($project->id);
        if ($benificiaries) {
            $project->benificiaries = $benificiaries;
        } else {
            $project->benificiaries = array();
        }

        //get budget list
        $budgets = $this->Budgets_model->get_project_budgets($project->id);
        if ($budgets) {
            $project->budgets = $budgets;
        } else {
            $project->budgets = array();
        }

        //get work packages
        $workpackages = $this->Workpackages_model->get_workpackages($project->id);
        $project->tasks = array();
        $tasks_count = 0;
        $subtasks_count = 0;
        if ($workpackages) {
            for ($i=0; $i<count($workpackages); $i++) {
                //get tasks of work package
                $tasks = $this->Tasks_model->get_wp_tasks($workpackages[$i]->id);
                if ($tasks) {
                    for($j=0; $j<count($tasks); $j++) {
                        //get sub task of parent task
                        $subtasks = $this->Tasks_model->get_wp_subtasks($tasks[$j]->id);
                        if ($subtasks) {
                            foreach($subtasks as $key => $subtask){
                              for($k=0;$k<count($subtask->task_leader);$k++){
                                $subtasks[$key]->beneficiary_short_name[$k] = $this->Beneficiaries_model->get_beneficiary_by_id($subtask->task_leader[$k]->participant_id)->short_name;
                              }
                            }

                            $tasks[$j]->subtasks = $subtasks;
                            $subtasks_count += count($subtasks);

                        } else {
                            $tasks[$j]->subtasks = array();
                        }
                        $tasks[$j]->wp_number = $workpackages[$i]->number;

                        if(count($tasks[$j]->task_leader) > 0){
                          for($k=0;$k<count($tasks[$j]->task_leader);$k++){
                            $tasks[$j]->beneficiary_short_name[$k] = $this->Beneficiaries_model->get_beneficiary_by_id($tasks[$j]->task_leader[$k]->participant_id)->short_name;
                          }
                        }
                        $tasks_count++;
                    }

                    $workpackages[$i]->tasks = $tasks;
                    $project->tasks[] = $tasks;
                } else {
                    $workpackages[$i]->tasks = array();
                }
            }
            $project->workpackages = $workpackages;
        } else {
            $project->workpackages = array();
        }

        //get list of deliverables
        $deliverables = $this->Deliverables_model->get_deliverables($project->id);
        if ($deliverables) {
            //get workpackage number
            for($cnt=0; $cnt<count($deliverables);$cnt++) {
                $wp_number = $this->Workpackages_model->get_workpackage($deliverables[$cnt]->wp_id, 'number');
                if ($wp_number) {
                    $deliverables[$cnt]->wp_number = $wp_number->number;
                } else {
                    $deliverables[$cnt]->wp_number = '';
                }
            }
            //add deliverables to projects array
            $project->deliverables = $deliverables;
        } else {
            $project->deliverables = array();
        }

        $this->data['project'] = $project;
        $this->data['rate'] = $rate;
        $this->data['tasks_count'] = $tasks_count;
        $this->data['tasks'] = $workpackages->tasks;
        $this->data['subtasks_count'] = $subtasks_count;
        $this->data['subtasks'] = $subtasks ;

        $this->data['project_monthly_salary'] = array(
            'name' => 'project_monthly_salary',
            'type' => 'text',
            'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('project_monthly_salary'),
            'class' => 'input-xlarge'
        );

        $this->data['project_hours_of_contract'] = array(
            'name' => 'project_hours_of_contract',
            'type' => 'text',
            'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('project_hours_of_contract'),
            'class' => 'input-xlarge'
        );

        $this->data['project_daily_hours_limit'] = array(
            'name' => 'project_daily_hours_limit',
            'type' => 'text',
            'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('project_daily_hours_limit'),
            'class' => 'input-xlarge'
        );
        $this->data['show_editprojects'] = 
            $this->auth_manager->get_authorization('projects','edit');
        $this->data['show_editworkpackages'] = 
           $this->auth_manager->get_authorization('workpackages','edit');
        $this->data['show_setbudgets'] = 
           $this->auth_manager->get_authorization('budgets','set');
        $this->data['show_editbudgets'] = 
           $this->auth_manager->get_authorization('budgets','edit');
        $this->data['show_deletebudgets'] = 
           $this->auth_manager->get_authorization('budgets','delete');
        $this->data['show_settingworkpackages'] = 
           $this->auth_manager->get_authorization('workpackages','set');
        $this->data['show_editworkpackages'] = 
           $this->auth_manager->get_authorization('workpackages','edit');
        $this->data['show_deleteworkpackages'] = 
           $this->auth_manager->get_authorization('workpackages','delete');
        $this->data['show_addtasks'] = 
           $this->auth_manager->get_authorization('tasks','add');
        $this->data['show_edittasks'] = 
           $this->auth_manager->get_authorization('tasks','edit');

        $this->data['show_deletetasks'] = 
           $this->auth_manager->get_authorization('tasks','delete');
        $this->data['show_addsubtasks'] = 
           $this->auth_manager->get_authorization('subtasks','add');
        $this->data['show_editsubtasks'] = 
           $this->auth_manager->get_authorization('subtasks','edit');
        $this->data['show_deletesubtasks'] = 
           $this->auth_manager->get_authorization('subtasks','delete');
        $this->data['show_editdeliverables'] =  
           $this->auth_manager->get_authorization('deliverables','edit');
        $this->data['show_deletedeliverables'] =   
           $this->auth_manager->get_authorization('deliverables','delete');
        $this->data['display_listofmilestones'] = 
           $this->auth_manager->get_authorization('List of Milestones','display');
        $this->data['set_beneficiaries'] = 
           $this->auth_manager->get_authorization('beneficiaries','set');
        $this->data['show_editbeneficiaries'] = 
           $this->auth_manager->get_authorization('beneficiaries','edit');
        $this->data['show_deletebeneficiaries'] = 
           $this->auth_manager->get_authorization('beneficiaries','delete');


        //initial view partshow_deleteworkpackages
        $this->data['content'] = $this->load->view('projects/show', $this->data, TRUE);

        //Render the page with the Helper function
        layout($this->data);
    } else {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Project not found.');
        redirect('projects', 'refresh');
    }
}
```

> how can i get rid of this error.is there any effect of this error

Comment: Could you post the `print_r($workpackages)` result?

Comment: it gives array as result.but when i try to print workpackages->tasks,it didn't show anything

Comment: Show some of the output array in your question please.

Comment: project_id: '4', tittle:'Organistation',number: '1',typr_of_activitty: 'MGT',wp_leader: '1',person_month: '38',start_month: '1',end_month: '48'

Comment: When I look at `$workpackages->tasks` I expect the `$workpackages` to be a `stdClass` which has a `tasks` item.